# kendo ui external template widgets

Tags: jquery, templates, kendo-ui, widget, external

I am trying to setup a SAP (single page app) with minimal initial markup for login. After login I am trying to load "main app template" to a dom body which defines splitters and tabstripes etc.

It kind of works, checking the dom, but external template widgets are never properly initialized. Splitters don't change to splitters, tabstripes not to tabs etc. Even if I manually call container.init or bind it doesn't render.

If I move html markup from external template to body, then everything works. I think I am missing some major concept thing here. Are external template just for simple stuff and maybe complete layout is too much. What am I missing? I see html markup in there, it seems to be "wrapped" by kendo, but it just doesn't render.

```
<div id="main">
<div id="tabstrip">
    <ul>
        <li class="k-state-active">Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>

    <div style="padding:0;overflow:hidden">
        <div id="grid"></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div id="split-horizontal2">

            <div>Left</div>

            <div id="contacts"></div>

            <div>Right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when template is loaded into DOM I call something like

```
var tabStrip = $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
        animation: false
    });
// also for splitters etc.
```

calling kendo.bind on #main or init on #main doesn't seem to effect anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I figured it out.
Seems like "kendo" requires a container in "body" - body element should not be used.
Once I placed a div container in body and later loaded external template into that div everything rendered well. I guess DOM body element can't or should not be used.